# apache httpd runs fine with root user but fails with non-root user

Tags: apache, permissions, root, httpd.conf, user-permissions

Apache httpd runs fine with `root` user. When i run apache with `oracle` user it fails to run and gives the below error:

```
$ id
uid=600000014(oracle) gid=63855(oinstall)
oracle@myhost:...ache/2.4.43/https-api11/bin$ ls -ltr apachectl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 oracle   oinstall    3509 Nov 10 05:09 apachectl

./apachectl -k start
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.23.52.219:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

$ telnet 10.23.52.219 443
Trying 10.23.52.219...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
oracle@myhost:...ache/2.4.43/https-vwsapi11/bin$ nslookup 10.23.52.219
216.51.23.10.in-addr.arpa       name = myhost.myshop.com.

oracle@myhost:...ache/2.4.43/https-api11/bin$ telnet myhost.myshop.com 443
Trying 10.23.52.219...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Below is some entries in the httpd.conf

```
Listen 8080
User oracle
Group oinstall
ServerAdmin weblogic@myshop.com
ServerName myhost.myshop.com

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

And finally in the `extra/httpd-ssl.com`

```
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/u/home/apache/2.4.43/https-api11/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost myhost.myshop.com:443>
DocumentRoot "/u/home/apache/2.4.43/https-api11/htdocs"
ServerName myhost.myshop.com
SSLEngine on

<Directory "/u/home/apache/2.4.43/https-api11/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

CustomLog "/u/home/apache/2.4.43/https-api11/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

ProxyPass /manager/ http://myhost.myshop.com:8443/manager/
ProxyPassReverse /manager/ http://myhost.myshop.com:8443/manager/

ProxyPass /api/ http://myhost.myshop.com:8443/api/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://myhost.myshop.com:8443/api/ timeout=600

SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

I will share entire configuration if the above info does not suffice.

Kindly suggest how can I get apache httpd to run with oracle user which is the user that was used to copy (install) it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache needs to run as root at first to bind itself on port 80 and 443 (or any port <= 1024).

```
User oracle
Group oinstall
```

works fine AFTER apache is up and needs to spawn child processes to handle requests (these processes will run as oracle:oinstall).

```
Listen 8080
```

means apache is listening on port 8080 and not on port 80 or 443 and works if apache isn't run as root.

You're also running mod_ssl which should include

```
Listen 443
```

by default unless you or someone else already changed the configuration so you need to change this value to something else (>1024) for the reason i wrote above.

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.23.52.219:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

means a virtual host is trying to bind itself on port 443 which is not working because apache isn't running as root.

IMHO you should install apache using an official package, let it run as root and configure it as you posted so the child process handling the requests are run as the use you like (a local user is preferred).